# Running Travis-CI using MochaJS, Supertest w/ Babel, Browserify, and Gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci, supertest

I've followed some tutorials and web casts on code school, mainly those on Node, ES2015, Angular, and Express. I've started a little project of my own and I've implemented all of the above. I'm also trying to get automated builds and testing working using Travis-CI and Mocha/Supertests for test driven development. The problem though is if I run `npm test` I get this error from Mocha

```
1)  Uncaught error outside test suite:
     Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
      at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
      at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
      at Server._listen2 (net.js:1236:14)
      at listen (net.js:1272:10)
      at Server.listen (net.js:1368:5)
      at EventEmitter.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (server/app.js:34:5)
      at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:6:11)
      at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at node.js:962:3
```

I just noticed that I was missing `module.exports = app` at the end of my main `app.js` that might have helped but the tests still fail.

Here is a link to the latest push on [GitHub](https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms).
Here is the failing build on [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/gh0st/ncps-mms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're currently getting on Travis CI is because NPM is trying to start your app with `node server/app.js` (as specified in [line 9 of your `package.json`](https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/blob/master/package.json#L9)), but your app requires MongoDB to be running (as specified [on line 13 of your `app.js`](https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/blob/master/server/app.js#L13)).

NPM has to start your app before it can run the tests.

MongoDB is available as a service on Travis CI. Have a look at the [Travis CI Database Setup docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MongoDB) and see how you go.

Comment: You're right and I'll probably have that error when I get to that point too but currently I'm trying to test using mocha on my local machine and I get this error.

Comment: I resolved my issue regarding testing not working locally. I'm pretty sure that didn't have anything to do with my Travis-CI failing but I fixed it anyway and after I did travis continued to fail. Once I followed your suggestion of adding mongodb to the `.travis.yml` Travis builds began working.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my `server/app.js` to listen if using

```
if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Listening on port " + port);
    });
}
```

Resolved my issue regarding testing not working on my local machine. The reason behind doing this can be found [here](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/10/eaddrinuse-when-watching-tests-with-mocha-and-supertest.html).
Also adding

```
services:
    - mongodb
```

like @ocean said worked, which reasoning can be referenced [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MongoDB).

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, well the error is that this Express app is trying to use a network port on your machine which is already being used by something else (maybe another Node / Express app, as they often use 3000).

Try changing the `var port` declaration near the bottom of `server/app.js` to be something other than 3000.

Comment: Hmm, weird. What did you change the port variable to? And have you pushed the latest code to GitHub so we can have a look at it?

Comment: Changed the port variable to 3030. Latest code is on Github. https://github.com/gh0st/ncps-mms/commit/9efa710d5d9d87926d5f967378ea894d5b47414a

Comment: Ok, no idea. I cloned your repo, ran `npm install`, then ran up a MongoDB in another terminal window, then ran `npm test` and it worked fine.

I also tried running the tests with the app already running (using `npm start`) in another terminal window, and the test ran fine then too.

Comment: I know. I fixed it. See my answer below.

Comment: Maybe your Node module versions are out of whack.

Try deleting your `node_modules` subdirectory inside the app repo, and then re-running `npm install`.

Comment: @gh0st Aha, didn't see that, whoops ;-)